# Electromagnetic transfer function

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, terminology

In a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0509067) on the superlens, I came across the term of ["transfer function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function). I understand that the transfer function relates the output to a given input, but I've been unable to find a formula for the transfer function which explains the effect upon the electric field through a superlens.

In *Optical Precursors: From Classical Waves to Single Photons* (Chen) on pg. 16, it says for

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2 E(z,\omega)}{\partial z^2}+k^2(\omega)E(z,\omega)=0,
\end{align}

the transfer function, $T(z,\omega)$, is found from
\begin{align}
E(z,\omega)=E(0,\omega)e^{ik(\omega)z}=E(z,0)T(z,w).
\end{align}

However, I also came across "electromagnetic transfer function" in [this paper](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1975LPSC....6.2927S/0002927.000.html) (pg.2928), which refers to the ratio of the amplitude of specific components of the magnetic field.

How do I know what transfer function the first paper is referring to? Is there a more general formula to determine the transfer function, preferably in two dimensions?

Comment: Transfer function is a fairly general term that refers to the relationship between the inputs and the outputs of a black box. What's inside the box doesn't matter.

Comment: If a transfer function is a general term, how should I interpret it when it is used in the context of lenses and electromagnetism? Or is the best way to email the author and ask what he was referring to? I'm a little hesitant to do that, though, in case it is supposed to be obvious from the context of the paper.

Comment: The same way you would interpret it in any other context: it's a function that takes the input variables and produces a model of the output variables. What that function is in detail depends on the context and you are required to understand the context before you can start working with its transfer functions.

Comment: Transfer function is a general term used for solving differential equations, the goal is obtain output function from the input. The thing is that when we apply a Laplace or Fourier transform to the diff equation, we get polynomial equation in the frequency domain and the $ f_{out} = T\cdot f_{in}$. And then you can use an inverse transform in order to get the answer in the time domain.